# How to hide New button in related list on lightning page layout?

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, page-layout

I would like to hide the "NEW" button from my lightning page layout-related list. I can do it for non-lighting page records from page layout by simply remove the new button from the related list but it is not working for the lightning record page.

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it's cached. Try to clear your browser cache.